# How Do I Check For Errors In The Console With Cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress

**Problem:** After researching stubbing, I am obtaining passing tests pages that I am receiving errors in.

**Code Example:**

```
it.only("test", () => {
  cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/endpoint");
  console.warn("ERROR");
  cy.stub(console, "error").as("consoleError");
  cy.stub(console, "warn").as("consoleWarn");
  cy.get("@consoleError").should("not.be.called");
  cy.get("@consoleWarn").should("not.be.called");
})
```

***Note:** Whilst I have added a warning here, there is also a warning when looking at the console of this page.*

[image: Warning Message On The Console]

**End Goal:** I would like to check whether pages show both errors and warnings as two separate tests for every page. I'll eventually be adding these tests to AWS Amplify Code Build.

**EDIT (ADDITIONAL INFORMATION BELOW):**

This example shows how even when wrapping, spying and waiting, the error is not detected.

```
it.only("test", () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/endpoint')
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    cy.wait(2000).then(() => {
      cy.wrap(cy.spy(win.console, 'error')).as('spyWinConsoleError');
      cy.get('@spyWinConsoleError').should('have.callCount', 0);
    })
  })
});
```

[image: Cypress Print Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal in the test is a bit obscure, not sure why you send the console warning from the test?

Anyway, if your research took you to this page [How do I spy on console.log?](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log) it would show you the correct way to check for errors in the console in a Cypress test.

> **How do I spy on console.log?**
>
> To spy on console.log you should use cy.stub().
>
> ```js
> cy.visit('/', {
>   onBeforeLoad(win) {
>     // Stub your functions here
>     cy.stub(win.console, 'log').as('consoleLog')
>   },
> })
>
> // Other test code
>
> cy.get('@consoleLog').should('be.calledWith', 'Hello World!')
> ```

Comment: With the end goal of *"I would like to check whether pages show both errors and warnings as two separate tests for every page."*, how can your answer be changed to help achieve this?

Comment: You could probably make your goal a bit more precise, but the obvious answer is to substitute `error` and `warn` in to code from the Cypress documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I re-read your code. Have a great day!